# Users and user roles not shown in WordPress when Toolset Type-Access is active

Tags: wordpress, user-roles, multisite

I just figured a strange behavior in the Toolset's **Type-Access** plugin. I think this si the same case as [this unresolved issue](https://toolset.com/forums/topic/toolset-access-is-clashing-with-wordpress-user-roles/).
I my case, it's a multisite context, so users can exists in others sites, specially super-admins.

Logged as super-admin, when Type-Access is active, the user-list of a blog is empty, so is the role list when I want to add a new user.

Strangely, in **cli** (`wp role list`, `wp user list`) -mode, users and roles are well shown.

Answer (score 2):

After many cache clear and transient deletion, I found the solution, diving in the code of Type-Access.

WordPress roles are filters via the `editable_roles` hook, which reliates to the `UserListing::get_excluded_roles` method. In shot, this method return the intersection of global roles and the current user's roles. But if the current user is **superadmin** and do not have explicit roles, this list is empty, and no roles nor users are displayed.

The solution is to manually add *administrator* role to any superadmin.

`wp user set-role THE_USERNAME administrator [--url=thesiteurl]`